# Changing the background color when audio is done

Tags: java, android, cardview

I'm new to java and i'm struggling with this for a long time. I'm making a soundboard and whenever a cardview is pressed i want it to play a sound and change the background color of the cardview for the duration of the audio. How can i make this happen? Playing the sound and changing the color are already working but i don't know how to set a duration or something. Can anyone help me out?

```
final MediaPlayer bingoMediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bingo);

final CardView bingo = (CardView) this.findViewById(R.id.play_bingo);

bingo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        bingoMediaPlayer.start();
        bingo.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FF6F00"));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"kekkkk", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reset the color when the audio is completed. For this you could use the OnCompletionListener.

```
  bingoMedia.setOnCompletionListener { 
      bingo.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("your_default_color")) 
  }
```

You can find the original documentation here: [MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener)

Comment: Happy to help, and welcome to Stack Overflow. If this answer or any other one solved your issue, please mark it as accepted.